# Gatsby develop no parsers registered for: "\"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to start my first gatsby project. When i try to start it, with`gatsby develop` or `npm start` I get an error:

`error UNHANDLED EXCEPTION`

`Error: no parsers registered for: "\"`

I searched about this error but couldn't find anything. I also tried to re install nodejs and gatsby but i got the same error. This is my first time trying to use it for a school project. Everyone from my class managed to start it but i have this same error everytime.

Comment: Which version of gatsby are you using?  Version 1 or 2?

Comment: @DanielGonzalez version 2.4.4

Comment: What version of Node.JS are you using?

Comment: @DanielGonzalez node  v11.1.0, npm 6.4.1

Comment: You might need to run gatsby on node.js 8.12, I am currently running node 9.5 ( I need to update) but it will not install the gatsby starter template for me. Is everyone in your class also running gatsby on NodeJS 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the path to the project folder with Gatsby has no spaces or č,š,ž,ć signs. It worked for me.
Example: 
Wrong - C:\Users\Public\Gatsby 1\my project
Right - C:\Users\Public\Gatsby_1\my_project

Comment: God bless your soul